# Restricting mouse coordinates to matplotlib figure window instead of using the coordinates of the whole computer screen?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

If there a way to restricting the mouse clicking event coordinates to just detect the coordinates into a matplotlb figure window instead of detecting the coordinates of the whole computer screen. You can see from the image that in my figure window it is at coordinates x=348, y= -149.2 but it prints the coordinates of the whole window screen at x=-1136 and y = 510.

[image]

I am using this

```
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=onMouseClick)
listener.start() # start thread
```

and

```
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button', on_click)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check in your `on_click` function:

```
def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes:
        # your current function body here
```